# Etale cohomology given by Hom functor in derived category

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory

Let $\text{Sm}/k$ be the category of smooth schemes over a field $k$ with etale topology. Suppose $\text{Sh}_{et}(\text{Sm}/k,\Lambda)$ be the etale sheaves of $\Lambda$ modules and the derived category of complexes of etale sheaves will be denoted by  $D^b(\text{Sh}_{et}(\text{Sm}/k,\Lambda))$. I seem to have seen that
\begin{equation}
\text{Hom}_{D^b(\text{Sh}_{et}(\text{Sm}/k,\Lambda))}(\Lambda(X),\mathcal{F}^*[n])=\mathbb{H}^n(X,\mathcal{F}^*)
\end{equation}
where $\Lambda(X)$ is the etale sheaf represented by $X$ which is considered as a complex concentrated at degree 0. Could any one give a proof?

I guess this is also true in general.

Comment: In the non-etale setting, the way you prove this is by resolving $\mathcal{F}$. What happens when you try to do the same here?

Comment: As KReiser said, there is nothing specific to the etale setting. This is a conjunction of two lemmas : $\operatorname{Hom}(\Lambda(X),\mathcal{F})=\Gamma(X,\mathcal{F})$, so their (hyper)-derived functor agree $\mathbb{R}^n\operatorname{Hom}(\Lambda(X),\mathcal{F}^.)=\mathbb{H}^n(X,\mathcal{F}^.)$. The second lemma is that the first group is actually a Hom in the derived category : $\mathbb{R}^n\operatorname{Hom}(A,B^.)=\operatorname{Hom}_{D^+}(A,B^.[n])$ (a lemma which can be found in any book on derived categories).

Comment: @KReiser Thank you for your hints.

Comment: @Roland Thank you, and I will read more derived category.